# Defining variables for strings in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

I'm using Microsoft Word from Office Professional Plus 2013. I have created a document with a text. At the beginning of the document I would like to create a variable which holds a string, for example `$test = "test"`. This variable I would like use later in the text to insert this string, for example:

```
This is a test sentence. Here we put the word $test.
```

So my goal is that then in this sentence the variable `$test` gets immediately replaced by the word `test`. So that I can just change the variable in the beginning and the text adapts then itself afterwards.

Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306281/how-to-store-and-retrieve-variables-in-word-documents You can set a document variable in a macro, and then refer to it in the document by inserting it as a field. Does this help?

Comment: Also see this question: https://superuser.com/questions/455344/microsoft-word-variable-without-macro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Word Variable without Macro](https://superuser.com/questions/455344/microsoft-word-variable-without-macro)